# Using CONCAT in column alias

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, ipython-magic, ipython-sql

I have a bunch of repeating queries in a Python accessed SQL notebook. I've tested the below

```py
colum_to_agg = f'''data_col_1'''

sql_aggregates_query=f'''
avg({colum_to_agg}) as (concat({colum_to_agg},'_mean')),
max({colum_to_agg}) as (concat({colum_to_agg},'_max')),
'''

print(sql_aggregates_query)
```

Which returns

```
avg(data_col_1) as (concat(data_col_1,'_mean')),
max(data_col_1) as (concat(data_col_1,'_max')),
```

Where i would like

```sql
avg(data_col_1) as data_col_1_mean,
max(data_col_1) as data_col_1_max,
```

I can get the query to run with

```py
colum_to_agg = f'''data_col_1'''

sql_aggregates_query=f'''
avg({colum_to_agg}) as {colum_to_agg}{'_mean'},
max({colum_to_agg}) as {colum_to_agg}{'_max'},
'''
print(sql_aggregates_query)
```

But am interested to know whether using concat in an alias is possible

Comment: is `concat` user defined function?

Comment: it's an `sql` standard

Answer (score 1):

Query can be written without the `concat` function.

```
colum_to_agg = f'''data_col_1'''

sql_aggregates_query=f'''
avg({colum_to_agg}) as {colum_to_agg}_mean,
max({colum_to_agg}) as {colum_to_agg}_max'''

print(sql_aggregates_query)
```

This should resolve the issue with query format.